# WSL not working after disabling enabling Virtual Machine platform feature

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Disabled **Virtual Machine platform** feature on windows-10. 
This caused WSL to stop working. Enabled it again and restarted windows. 
But still WSL doesn't work. If I type wsl it just waits ...nothing happens.
What could be the reason for this and how to fix it ?

Adding screenshot containing output of commands : 
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall WSL?  If you type `wsl --list --verbose` what is the output?  You can [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Also recommend providing the output of `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -online -FeatureName "VirtualMachinePlatform"` and `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -online -FeatureName "Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux"` as an edit to the question.  You will need to run these in an elevated PowerShell session ("Run as Administrator" or `Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb RunAs`)

Comment: If I open Apps in Microsoft App store it does show WSL Installed. But if I click on launch. A window pops up and nothing happens. Just like in the screenshots that I attached `wsl --list -verbose` command just hangs